# Issue with Sidekiq rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am trying to to run this below command for Sidekiq.

```
 bundle exec sidekiq
```

I am getting below error and Can't able to run jobs with sidekiq.

```
$ bundle exec sidekiq
Note: Google::Cloud::Logging is disabled because it failed to authorize with the service. (Unable to read the credential file specified by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: file /home/app/config/secrets/pubsub-credentials.json does not exist) Falling back to the default Rails logger.

INFO: Booting Sidekiq 5.1.1 with redis options {:url=>"redis://redis:6379/0", :role=>:master, :password=>"REDACTED", :id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-10968"}


         m,
         `$b
    .ss,  $$:         .,d$
    `$$P,d$P'    .,md$P"'
     ,$$$$$bmmd$$$P^'
   .d$$$$$$$$$$P'
   $$^' `"^$$$'       ____  _     _      _    _
   $:     ,$$:       / ___|(_) __| | ___| | _(_) __ _
   `b     :$$        \___ \| |/ _` |/ _ \ |/ / |/ _` |
          $$:         ___) | | (_| |  __/   <| | (_| |
          $$         |____/|_|\__,_|\___|_|\_\_|\__, |
        .d$$                                       |_|

INFO: Running in ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-linux]
INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
/vendor/cache/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:210:in `getaddrinfo'
```

I also checked redis

```
$redis-cli ping
PONG
$ redis-server
1991:C 07 Sep 17:11:54.900 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1991:C 07 Sep 17:11:54.901 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1991, just started
1991:C 07 Sep 17:11:54.901 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
1991:M 07 Sep 17:11:54.901 # You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
1991:M 07 Sep 17:11:54.901 # Server can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
1991:M 07 Sep 17:11:54.901 # Current maximum open files is 4096. maxclients has been reduced to 4064 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
1991:M 07 Sep 17:11:54.901 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use
```

Help me to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which `environment` are you running this on ? Do you have `redis` running ?

Comment: Please add full log which error you get

Comment: A wild guess, you don't have a redis running on your machine, which is needed by sidekiq. Also, is this the whole errror?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I cehck and redis is ruining

Comment: @siegy22 I updated my Question with full error log

Comment: The last line of your output from the `redis-server` command suggests Redis isn't actually starting because the Address 6379 is already in use.

Answer (score 1):

To run sidekiq you need a redis server:

> Redis provides data storage for Sidekiq. It holds all the job data along with runtime and historical data to power Sidekiq's Web UI.

From the documentation:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/The-Basics#redis
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis

If your redis server runs anywhere else than `localhost:6379`, you can [configure the URL](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis).

To setup a local redis server, you can install it with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install redis
redis-server # will run the server on `localhost:6379`
```

Then in a second shell window, try to launch sidekiq:

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

Comment: They have redis running, allegedly.

Comment: Oh didn't see that in the comments, they were collapsed apparently, updated the answer, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You set sidekiq to use redis at `redis://redis:6379/0`, but that's not a valid url on your system. In particular, host `redis` can't be resolved to an IP address.